# Why the id of float values are different when the same value is assigned to two different variables?

Tags: python, types

Why the id of float values are different when the same value is assigned to two different variables?

```
a = 10.20
b = 10.20

print(a is b)
False

print(a is not b)
True

print(id(a), id(b))
2449430561168 2449429859408
```

Comment: The same two strings will be allocated two different memory spaces.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "good answer" to questions like this: you're staring at undefined implementation details. `is` is only meant to test for object identity, not object equality. For immutable objects (like floats), it's wholly undefined whether equality implies identity.

And it can change, depending on context and on which version of Python is in use. Here under the released Python 3.10.1, running in IDLE:

```
>>> a = 10.20
>>> b = 10.20
>>> a is b
False
>>> if 1:
...     a = 10.20
...     b = 10.20
...     print(a is b)
True
```

Why do they differ? A wise man once said "there's no good answer to questions like this" ;-)

In fact it's an accident of the current implementation: if a float *literal* is repeated in a *single* code block, only one instance of the object is created. That's what happens in the second (`if 1:`) example. But at the start, each line is compiled separately in its own code block, and nothing about literals appearing in one code block is remembered in the next block. Two different float objects *happen* to be created for the two instances of the literal `10.20`. But that's not *defined* behavior either: it's just what the implementation happens to do today.

What is defined? After `a = b`, and regardless of what object `b` is bound to, `a is b` must be `True`. That's the heart of "object identity".

Answer (score 0):

Because the docs say that the ID will be unique, it doesn't matter what the variable holds, the value will always be unique.

> This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id

Answer (score 0):

This is because `is` keywords tests whether two variables belong to the same object. Here both the int objects are different as they're guaranteed to be unique always.

Use `==` instead to check of they are equals.